# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Problem

Tags: google-sheets

I want to set the background colour of 3 adjacent cells based upon a formula.

I've followed the guidelines etc.. and have selected the range of cells, but when the conditions of the formula are met, the background colour of only the first cell in the range is set to the stipulated colour, the other 2 remain white  (no fill colour).

Has anyone else seen this problem? And is there a fix?

Thank kindly.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Please describe the columns (with their names) of the image and also column B (absent from the attached image)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place a $ sign to lock your column reference, so the custom formula must be something like this:

```
=$H2*$B$9-$B$12<=0
```

*Note that we don't know nothing about column B*

[image: c f]

Comment: Thanks kindly, problem solved, much appreciated